# precise synchronization using semaphore using FreeRTOS , is it possible?

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, semaphore, rtos

I am using the FreeRTOS semaphore API functions in my project for task synchronization and handling the shared resources. I am able to achieve task synchronization up to 500us. I need the semaphores to be more precise.

1. I have used FreeRTOS API functions to create the semaphore and access the shared resources but I am unable to go below 500us for synchronization. The reason being the context switch that takes the CPU time to save the state of the thread.
   So in order to avoid this, I think having own semaphore library would help

Can anyone please guide me if this would be the correct approach or is there any other alternative that can solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why/how do you think having your own semaphore library is going to avoid the context switch time?

Comment: This is clearly an XY problem. In my experience FreeRTOS is a little slower than other RTOS but context switch times are in the order of 15us on a 72Mhz STM32F1XX for example (you don't specify your part or core frequency). It is unclear without example code what you are measuring, how you are measuring it, or what you mean by "precise". Something else is going on here if it takes that long. Ask how to fix the problem rather than how to implement what you think is the solution (it's not).

Comment: @Clifford context switch on ARM uC takes from 100 to about 400 clocks (1.5 to 6us with 72MHz)

Comment: RTOS semaphores use basically the queues and they are not too efficient. But direct task notifications are fast and lightweight

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland : it was years ago I tested it, possibly a debug build, and armcc V4, so clearly YMMV, also the test method may have been measuring more than context switch. It was a comparative test in which Keil RTX was 5us, and Segger embOS 10us. Either way 500us is a different order of magnitude entirely. Which is why we need to see the OPs test code and measurement method.

Comment: @P__JsupportswomeninPoland Indeed, most RTOS objects in FreeRTOS are based on queues. It is why it is slower than other RTOS. In most RTOS, complex constructs such as a queue are implemented using more primative elements such as mutexes and semaphores, but bizarrely IMO, FreeRTOS constructs the simple from the complex. 500us remains implausible though.